# Bouncy Castle API for creating Asymmetric Key Pair

Tags: c#, asp.net, cryptography, bouncycastle

I am using the Bouncy Castle API to create a Key Pair but I am running into two errors, it would either be:

```
DER length more than 4 bytes: XXX
```

or something like:

```
DEF length __ object truncated by __
```

Here is my code, I am trying to create an AsymmetricKeyParameter using the ephemeral public key from Google Pay's token

```
// Decode and convert to Byte Array
byte[] ephemeralPublicKeyBytes = Base64.Decode(signedMessage["ephemeralPublicKey"]);
// Drop first byte for formatting (0x04)
ephemeralPublicKeyBytes = ephemeralPublicKeyBytes.Skip(1).ToArray();
//Create AsymmetricKeyParamter (ERROR)
AsymmetricKeyParameter pubAKP = PublicKeyFactory.CreateKey(ephemeralPublicKeyBytes);
```

I am not quite sure what's wrong. I am using iTextsharper which contains Bouncy Castle's 5.5.11.0 API

Comment: What is the size of the public key? Could you display the public key bytes as hexadecimals?

Answer (score 0):

The method you are calling creates a key from a `SubjectPublicKeyInfo` structure. This is a structure that is found in X.509 certificates (like the ones used for HTTPS in your browser). Unfortunately, that's not what you have.

That first `04` is very likely an indicator byte for a *uncompressed point format*, after which the `x` and `y` follow as two, concatenated, statically sized, unsigned, big endian coordinates of the public key. So in that case you need to retrieve the parameters for your specific curve, and then use those to parse the point.

In principle the `04` could also be an octet string indicator. In that case you would need to skip the length bytes that follow it as well. Or you could parse it as an ASN.1 octet string and request the value.

---

Some idea on how to do this in Java / BC - happy porting, I don't have the time.

```
public static ECPublicKeyParameters parseECPublicKeyPoint(String curveName, byte[] point) throws Exception {

    X9ECParameters curveParams = ECNamedCurveTable.getByName(curveName);

    ECCurve curve = curveParams.getCurve();

    // the point will be validated so it should be on the curve... if the right curve was chosen anyway
    ECPoint decodePoint = curve.decodePoint(point);

    // stupid conversion still needed for some inexplicable reason
    ECDomainParameters domainParams = new ECDomainParameters(curve, curveParams.getG(), curveParams.getN(), curveParams.getH());
    ECPublicKeyParameters ecPublicKeyParameters = new ECPublicKeyParameters(decodePoint, domainParams);

    return ecPublicKeyParameters;
}
```

Note that the C# API/implementation of Bouncy Castle generally follows the Java implementation, so porting this should be mainly a case of capitalizing the first letter of the function calls.

Comment: And my Mickeysoft mouse keeps eating batteries like there is no tomorrow. I'll try and get my Logitech Marathon mouse going before I'm completely out. Feel free to owe me a S2 mouse or something similar :P

Comment: You are right, ephemeralPublicKeyBytes initially has 65 bytes and the first one denotes the format. Now I am passing a 64-byte long public key into the method (each 32 bytes representing the X and Y points on the elliptic curve ). Also, the method I'm calling actually has 2 overloads:
CreateKey(byte[])
CreateKey(Stream)
CreateKey(SubjectPublicKeyInfo)

Comment: Did you try my code? You should not remove the 04 if you use the byte[] variant of the function, it expects an encoded point.